# Finding the Corresponding Value of a Key in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary where i am trying to print the corresponding value of the nested key without requiring the outermost numeral key input.

e.g. if `roomname` in nested-nested dictionary, print room area.

and my dictionary is set up like below:

```
d = {0: {'RoomName': 'PSC', 'MinArea': '28', 'MinRoomDim': 'null', 'MinDoorWidth': '900', 'MinDoorHeight': '2100', 'NoofDoorLeaves': '1', 'DoorMaterial': 'Glass', 'ReferenceLocation': 'LTA ADC SECTION 3.1 CLAUSE 5.1', 'RoomSpecificInfo': 'Refer to PSC design guidelines'}, 
     1: {'RoomName': 'SMR', 'MinArea': '8', 'MinRoomDim': 'null', 'MinDoorWidth': '900', 'MinDoorHeight': '2100', 'NoofDoorLeaves': '1', 'DoorMaterial': 'Glass', 'ReferenceLocation': 'LTA ADC SECTION 3.1 CLAUSE 5.2', 'RoomSpecificInfo': 'null'}, 
     2: {'RoomName': 'FIRST AID RM', 'MinArea': '7.5', 'MinRoomDim': '3.0m x 2.5m', 'MinDoorWidth': '1000', 'MinDoorHeight': '2100', 'NoofDoorLeaves': '1', 'DoorMaterial': 'null', 'ReferenceLocation': 'LTA ADC SECTION 3.1 CLAUSE 5.3', 'RoomSpecificInfo': 'null'},...
```

So far all the solutions I managed to find are for typical dictionaries and the solution does not work for nested dictionaries like above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can print nested dictionaries like this:

```
for i,j in d.items():
    for m,n in j.items():
        print(m,n)
```

where m is the key and n is the value of the nested dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Read the json file and then use multiple loads and `get()` inside to get the required value in the nested json for example to get in key '1' to get RoomName

```
json.loads(json.loads(x).get("1","{}")).get("RoomName"))
```